# 406 Not Acceptable error when submitting my form

Tags: php, apache

I have a strange, new issue on a system I've been using for years. There is a form on my front end website (Apache server, PHP and Mysql) that anyone is allowed to fill - a careers application form. Then, on a simple PHP backend, we can view this application data, and also have the ability to edit the form and add manager-notes.

For one application (which looks fine, maybe some Word-pasted bullets but nothing too special), I tried editing the data - the form loaded fine - but when I submit the form, Apache reports a "406" error,

*Not Acceptable*

*An appropriate representation of the requested resource /accounts/network.php could not be found on this server.*

*Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.*

I'm confused. Submitting the other forms works fine, it's just this application. Also, the front-end seemed to have accepted his data, so I'm not sure why the backend is not. Can anyone advise, what can I do in PHP or Firebug (Firefox) to investigate what is going wrong?

When loading the form, (before submitting), here are my response headers (from the NET tab in Firebug)

```
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  21372
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Sat, 15 Sep 2012 09:43:23 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=10, max=10
Server  Apache
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.2.17
Request Headersview source
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Authorization   Basic cmlzaGk6MjR0b255MzAwMw==
Connection  keep-alive
Host    www.mydomain.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
```

Many thanks!

**[UPDATE]**
Further I have pasted my code as requested to help solve thus. 
1) .htaccess - my main domain .htaccess is empty, but the admin area has a .htaccess as well with simple password protection. 
(AuthType Basic

require valid-user)

2) PHP info of my CMS area is here: http://jaysonsgroup.com/info.php
However the "front end" website is a different website/domain on the same server. Therefore the PHP info will be the same on that site too.

3) HTML Form code is here. Actually I've pasted all the HTML minus some unnecessary longer parts which have nothing to do with the form. Some  elements are also stripped out since they don't have problems on other form applications.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Admin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<script langauge="Javascript" src="js/jfunctions.js"></script>
<script langauge="Javascript">

function validateForm(form) {
    if (isWhitespace(form.title.value)) {
        alert("Please choose your title.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

</script>


    <form method='post' action='/accounts/network.php?op=view' onsubmit='return validateForm(this)'>
    <table class='noborder' width=100% cellpadding=1 >

    <tr>
    <td align='left'><span class='fieldname'>Title*</span></td>
    <td align='left'>

    <select size='1' name='title'>
    <option value=''>[Please choose]</option>

        <option  value='Dr'>Dr</option>

        <option  selected='selected'  value='Mr'>Mr</option>

        <option  value='Mrs'>Mrs</option>

        <option  value='Miss'>Miss</option>

        <option  value='Ms'>Ms</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='left'><span class='fieldname'>Surname*</span></td>
    <td align='left'><input type='text' name='surname' size='22' maxlength='30' value='test' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='left'><span class='fieldname'>Forename(s)*</span></td>
    <td align='left'><input type='text' name='forenames' size='22' maxlength='50' value='test' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='left' width='30%'><span class='fieldname'>Your Company Name (if applicable)</span></td>
    <td align='left' width='70%'><input type='text' name='company_name' size='22' maxlength='50' value='' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='left'><span class='fieldname'>Address</span></td>
    <td align='left'><textarea rows=2 cols=22 name='address'>test</textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='left' width='30%'><span class='fieldname'>City*</span></td>
    <td align='left' width='70%'><input type='text' name='city' size='22' maxlength='50' value='Rathnapura' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='left'><span class='fieldname'>Country of Residence*</span></td>
    <td align='left'><select name='country' size='1'>{options will be here - I have taken them out as they are very long for this post}</select></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='left'><span class='fieldname'>Contact number(s)</span></td>
    <td align='left'><input type='text' name='tel_nos' size='22' maxlength='50' value='+12345' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='left'><span class='fieldname'>Email*</span></td>
    <td align='left'><input type='text' name='email' size='22' maxlength='50' value='test@gmail.com' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td></tr>

    <tr>
    <td><span class='fieldname'>Other skills (use this box to elaborate on your skills, including any others that are not listed above)</span></td>
    <td><textarea rows='9' cols='35' name='sk_otherdesc' ></textarea>
    </td></tr>

    <tr>
    <td><span class='fieldname'>Please specify the areas of work in which you are most interested.*</span></td>
    <td><textarea rows='6' cols='35' name='interestareas' >PHP web base application developments</textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><textarea rows='9' cols='35' name='samplework' >•   I have developed ....

•   I have developed dynamic web site ....


•   I have developed a PHP web base application named .....Link- http://test ....

</textarea></td>
    </tr>


    <tr><td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan='2' class='tabledivider'>Other info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><textarea rows='5' cols='35' name='moreinfo' >I m following my degree program in weekend.  </textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='left' width='30%'><span class='fieldname'>Manager Rating</span></td>
    <td align='left' width='70%'><input type='text' name='manager_rating' size='5' maxlength='10' value='0' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><span class='fieldname'>Manager Notes</span></td>
    <td><textarea rows='5' cols='35' name='manager_notes' ></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

            <!-- Button to update record -->
    <br/><input type="hidden" name="status" value="submitted"/><input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="177" /><input type="submit" value="Update Entry"/>
</form> 


</div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please post your html form code & phpinfo() result here ? it will help us to debug your issue

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, I just updated the post. Note that the form was a bit long so I cut out some parts that are common and also changed some of his personal/application data to protect privacy.

Comment: can you also paste the REQUEST headers please?

Comment: Sorry, request headers are pasted just below the response headers above, let me know if I need to reformat this? The NET tab in Firebug also says: Request Headers From Upload Stream
Content-Length 1523
Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded